# Graph theory question about vertices represented as multiple sets

Tags: graph-theory

[image: Graph theory]

I have a beginner Graph theory question. We just started learning it for my discrete math class and I'm confused about the wording of this question. In the examples done in class and in the textbook, the set of vertices is always represented as a single set of finite integers.

In this question however, it says the vertices are the **sets** {a,b}. Could someone clarify what exactly this means and the implications of this, as well as any hints for the question?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Fix $n$ to be $5$, the minimum allowable value. Take pairs of distinct numbers from $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, e.g. $\{2,3\}$. These are your vertices. How many of them can you find? Which ones are joined by edges? Duplicate the same experiment with different values of $n$.

Comment: Ohh right I see now, thanks for the clarification.